# show product images in wizard

Tags: xml, python-2.7, wizard, odoo-10

How to show product images in wizard? I am trying to show all images of product in a wizard but stucks at an error.

here is my code:-

py code:-

```
from openerp import api, fields, models, _
from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID
from openerp.exceptions import UserError
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp

class image_wizard(models.TransientModel):
     _name = "image.wizard"

      image_medium = fields.Many2many("Images")





       @api.multi
       def action_image_add(self):
          rec = self._context.get('active_ids', [])
          print "REC", rec, self.product_id.categ_id #product_uom
          if rec:
              line_values = {'image_medium': self.image_medium
                       }
              sale_order_line = self.env['product.template'].create(line_values)
```

xml code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="view_image_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Image wizard</field>
        <field name="model">image.wizard</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Sales Pack">
                <group colspan="4" col="4">
                    <group colspan="4" col="4">
                        <field name="image"/>

                    </group>
                </group>
                <footer>
                    <button name="action_image_add" string="Ok" type="object"
                            class="btn-primary"/>
                    <button string="Cancel" class="btn-default" special="cancel"/>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="action_view_image_wizard" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Image wizard</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">image.wizard</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_image_wizard"/>
        <field name="target">new</field>
    </record>

</data>
```

xml code:-

```
    <record id="product_template_pack_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.productpack.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <xpath expr="//field[@name='image_medium']" position="before">
                <button name="%(action_view_image_wizard)d" string="see all images" type="action"/>
            </xpath> 
        </field>
     </record>
```

But it shows an error "External ID not found in the system: product_pack.action_view_image_wizard".

Is there any error in my code? can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: Have you all this code in the folder alone? or not.

Comment: I have all this code in one folder.

Comment: what is the name of your folder?

Comment: The name of my folder is name of my module.

Answer (score 1):

you can call your XML edit by **folder_name.xml_id**

```
<record id="product_template_pack_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.productpack.form</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <xpath expr="//field[@name='image_medium']" position="before">
            <button name="%(image_wizard.action_view_image_wizard)d" string="see all images" type="action"/>
        </xpath> 
    </field>
 </record>
```

Comment: How to save these images in wizard when ok button is clicked because when I click on ok button, the selected images disappears?

Comment: Wizard records are not meant to be persistent; they are automatically deleted from the database after a certain time. This is why they are called transient. Link Doc odoo :https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html#wizards

Answer (score 0):

i think you might have error of "External ID not found in the system:"
because in the xml file you have type the wrong id name. your record id should be the name of the function from the py file.
so instead of this: ***"record id="action_view_image_wizard" model="ir.actions.act_window"***
it should be like this: ***record id="action_image_add" model="ir.actions.act_window"***